# Dynamically Changing "template" layout.updatemenus[] Dropdown

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a Python Dash App which display a Plotly graph_object.timeline with only one trace (I think this problem should not depend in the amount of traces).
I want a layout.updatemenus dropdown button that allos me to change the template of the graph ( between "plotly", "plotly_white", "plotly_dark", etc)

Here it is a minimal reproducible code for what I have been trying.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash import Dash, dcc, html

# import plotly.io as pio
# pio.templates.default = "ggplot2"

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28', Resource="Alex"),
    dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-03-05', Finish='2009-04-15', Resource="Alex"),
    dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30', Resource="Max")
])

# fig = go.Figure()
fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Resource", color="Resource")

fig.update_layout(updatemenus=[
        dict(
          active=1,
          showactive=True,
          buttons=list(
            [
              dict(args=[{"type": "line", 'xbins.size': 900000}, ],label="15Min"),
              dict(args=[{"type": "histogram",'xbins.size': 3600000}, ],label="Hour", method="update")
            ]
              ),
          font=dict(color="black", size=12)
        ),
        dict(
          direction="right",
          active=1, #0,
          showactive=True,
          buttons=list(
            [
              dict(args=[{"template": 'plotly_white'}], label="White",method="relayout"),
              dict(args=[{"template": 'plotly_dark'}], label="Dark",method="relayout")
            ]
          ),
          font=dict(color="black")
        )
    ]
  )

# fig.update_layout(template="plotly_dark")

app = Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id = 'my_graph',figure=fig)
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

While the first button list works, the second one doesn't.
Whenever I chose an option the templates is set to "plotly_white". So at first (starting with a dark template) it seems to work. But whatever template I set as default, whatever template I set the fig layout, and whatever options I put in the buttons list, when selecting one option for the first time the template is always set to "plotly_white", and selecting other option for the second  and subsequent times nothing happens (It always remains as "plotly_white".

Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Note: I found a solution changing templates using

```py
from dash_bootstrap_templates import ThemeSwitchAIO
```

but I would rather prefer an alternative using updatemenus if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the frontend (plotly.js) has no knowledge of those template names and their respective configuration which are specific to plotly.py, so it expects an object that defines the template rather than a string referring to it.

To fix this, you need to pass the full template object in the button `args` using `plotly.io` as follows :

```py
# updatemenus button config 
buttons=[
    dict(args=['template', pio.templates['plotly_white']], label="White", method="relayout"),
    dict(args=['template', pio.templates['plotly_dark']], label="Dark", method="relayout")
],
```

For reference, here are the [template configuration objects](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/tree/master/packages/python/plotly/plotly/package_data/templates) that are generated and made available to the frontend when using the python package.

Comment: Great! Thank you!
I was thinking something similar bc when I passed an arbitrary string I had the same behavior;  but when I wanted some documentation about how to get the template as an object I only found this [Representing themes with Template objects](https://plotly.com/python/templates/#representing-themes-with-template-objects)
With your solution is working as expected.